# Stokes theorem for intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute the line integral of $\ F = \left \langle (z-1)^2, x^3, y^3 \right \rangle$ over the curve formed by the intersection of $\ z = x^2 + y^2 $ and $\ 2x+2y+z=1$.

Using Stokes theorem we get $\nabla \times F = 3 \left \langle y^2,(z-1)^2,x^3 \right \rangle $ and the unit normal vector is just $\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\left \langle 1,1,0 \right \rangle $. On our plane, $z = 1-2x-2y$. Exchanging $z$ with that stuff in our equation gives us:

$$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt 2}\int\int (4x²+5y²+8xy) \rm dx \rm dy$$

Over the surface bounded by $\ z = 1 -2x -2y$ and $\ z = x^2 + y^2$. This gives the circle $$\ (x+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+(y+\dfrac{1}{2})^2 = 3$$.

Switching to polar coordinates here gives me something integratable, but very nasty. Is there a better way to do all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to polar coordinates with a shift: $x=-1/2+r\cos\theta$, $ y=-1/2+r\sin\theta$. The the integration region is $0\le r\le 3$, $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$. And the function to be integrated consists of assorted powers of cosines and sines, which are easy to integrate over the period $[0,2\pi]$.